# Pass json data as parameter using angular js and receive that in Web API method

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

We have a method on WebAPI and we are calling it from angularjs, we want to pass json data as parameter and receive it as object in WebAPI method.
**AngularJS Call**
`var empInfo = {
            EmployeeNumber: 123
        };`
`$http.post('/EmployeeArrivalDetails/UpdateEmployeeApprovalStatus/', empInfo).
        then(function (response) {
           }, function (response) {
});`

**WebAPI method**
 `[HttpPost]`
`public ReturnResponse  UpdateEmployeeApprovalStatus(Employee employeeInfo)
{
}`

Comment: you construct `employeeInfo` instance,but then pass `empInfo` to action.

Comment: Yes , we have changed it.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve as object and using Newtonsoft.you  can convert back it to object i think it may help u

```
[HttpPost]
public ReturnResponse  UpdateEmployeeApprovalStatus(object employeeInfo)
{
     Employee emp= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employee>(employeeInfo.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I tried but getting 404 error. `http://localhost:13832/EmployeeArrivalDetails/UpdateEmployeeApprovalStatus/ `                                                                    Scripts/angular.js:12185

Comment: Check your route .if it is right do a clean and rebuild

Comment: Tried this....but didn't work. But Other method(which is accepting only parameter) on this controller is working fine.

Comment: @Naqi PostUpdateEmployeeApprovalStatus Change your method name preceding with post and also please update your question with route :)

Answer (score 0):

Your above code should work. Now..

There are few common reasons for getting 404 from web api:

1. web api request url is not right
2. Route is not define properly or it is conflicting with other route definition.
3. Adding following code in web config works fine:

> `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />`

Hope this will help you. 
Cheers!